# Webpack UglifyJs Unexpected Token

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I keep getting this error when I'm executing my `npm run build`
and the really weird part is that when I'm running `npm run watch` the compilation finishes successfully.

```
ERROR in rbz_bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (,) [xxx.js:102316,12]
```

This is my package.json dependencies and scripts:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"production\"' --progress --colors --config ./webpack.prod.config.js",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server -d --hot --inline --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"development\"' --progress --colors --watch --config ./webpack.dev.config.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "firebase": "^4.10.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.34",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "eslint": "^4.18.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.6.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-replace-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-watch-livereload-plugin": "0.0.1",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

and from some unknown reason I can't get this fixed, I saw people suggesting to add `"uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony"` but it didn't do anything for me.

------ EDIT: Webpack.prod.js ------

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')
var extractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
require("babel-polyfill")

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js')
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'xxx', 'static', 'js'),
    publicPath: '../xxx/static/js',
    filename: 'xxx.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        loader: extractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new extractTextPlugin({
      filename: '../xxx/static/css/xxx.css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update your webpack config?

Comment: I've added the webpack file

Comment: Can you share your .babelrc file?

Answer (score 0):

It seem webpack doen't support this way `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin`

You might to try to use by this way:

`const WebpackUglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack-uglify-js-plugin');`

Put in the top to declare plugin

```
module.exports.plugins.push(

        new WebpackUglifyJsPlugin({
            cacheFolder: path.resolve(__dirname, 'target'),
            debug: true,
            minimize: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            output: {
                comments: false
            },
            compressor: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    );
```

See the document from [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#usage)

Comment: Did you remove `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin`?

Comment: Yes, I've replaced it with the webpackUglifyjsPlugin inside the plugins